# Can't add album to facebook page with C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm driving myself to despair trying to get an album added to a facebook page using the C# SDK..

I *think* my code is OK as I can successfully create an album on my own profile page through the SDK and API. So, I expect something's getting confused with my access tokens and permissions etc.

My c# code is here:

```
string accessToken = "TOKEN HERE";

FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var albumParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
albumParameters["message"] = "new message";
albumParameters["name"] = "new name";
facebookClient.Post("/412639422128107/albums", albumParameters);
```

The error Im getting is:
(OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred.

I've read loads of posts on here and elsewhere on the web about getting the page's access token. Which I'm pretty sure I'm doing right -

1. I go to this page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
2. I type in "me/accounts"
3. I see a couple of pages i'm the admin of, and grab the access token that corresponds with my page id that i'm trying to add the album to (412639422128107)
4. I check the permissions on this access token by going here:
   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=
5. I see that I've got the following permissions: create_event, create_note, manage_pages, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, read_stream, share_item, status_update, video_upload

But, I'm clearly not doing something quite right as it's not working! Please could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks loads in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an album in the facebook page with this code.

```
string accessToken = "";

FacebookWebClient fbApp = new FacebookWebClient();


dynamic parametersForToken = new ExpandoObject();
parametersForToken.fields = "access_token";
try
{
  dynamic me = fbApp.Get(idExternalPage, parametersForToken);
  accessToken = me.access_token;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return;
}


FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var albumParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
albumParameters["message"] = "new message";
albumParameters["name"] = "new name";
facebookClient.Post("/me/albums", albumParameters);
```

or try this

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path='Page_Id'%3Ffields%3Daccess_token
```

Sorry i'm testing my script, and i have the same problem. (only for creating gallery)

see this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/376442565760536?browse=search_50361119879b15494037772 (the bug is fixed)

Comment: Aaah thanks TianZi, I ran it just now and it seems to be working fine without me changing anything (although if there're no photos in the album it doesn't show up on the page), thanks for the link to the bug - that explains everything, FB must have fixed it at their end now. :)